# Cypress and Javascript: Logging function gives a blank

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, cypress

I have a function that is looping through arrays and giving me numbers as the output. It is working correctly because the `cy.get(values)` gives what I want. However, when I try to call `cy.log(<func>)` I get a blank (undefined). I'm not sure what's going on.

```
const func = () => {
        const nums = numArray.get() 
        let new = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            const arr = nums[i].temps
            arr.forEach((element) => {
                new.push(element.aggregate)
            })
        }
     cy.get(new) 
}
```

[image]

However, when I do this in my it function it gives me a blank or undefined

```
it('test', function () {
    ..........
    cy.log(func())
  }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help here?

Comment: please provide the full code. my try with mocked `const nums = [{ temps: [{aggregate: 1 }]}, { temps: [{aggregate: 2 }] }, { temps: [{aggregate: 3 }] }]` works as expected and prints `log [1, 2, 3]`. I bet there is some cypress command in the call chain that makes impossible to use `func()` result directly

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything in your function, so there is nothing for the `cy.log()` to display. Try returning the values.

```js
const func = () => {
        const nums = numArray.get() 
        let new = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            const arr = nums[i].temps
            arr.forEach((element) => {
                new.push(element.aggregate)
            })
        }
        return new
}
```

Comment: still returns blank when calling cy.log(func())